# NSString character position

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *url = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
```

How can I get the character position of the 4th "/" ?

Comment: What you mean by 4th "/", first the 4th character is not "/". Or if you mean the the 4th "/" in all "/", which corresponds to the last one "/ask"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the last part of the url, you should be able to use this:

```
NSArray* items = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

To get the index of the last '/' character:

```
NSRange range = [url rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```

get the index value from `range.location`

To find the index of the fourth '/' character from the url:

```
int count = 0;
int index = -1;
for (unsigned int i=0; i < [url length]; ++i) {
    if ([url characterAtIndex:i] == '/') {
        ++count;
        if (count == 4) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not always the last one, it's the 4th one

Answer (score 7):

Usually you don't have to get the index of the letter /. You can just use many convenience methods defined in `NSURL`, see [this Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I would do

```
  NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"];
  NSString* last=[url lastPathComponent]; // last is now @"ask"
```

Answer (score 5):

another way you can use

```
[url rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location
```

hope it help!

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to manually do "logical" linebreaks on a string (i.e. breaking at a space) to spit out a string in multiple CCLabelTTF blocks, and this was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I editted my answer after understanding your problem.

The answer of Hitesh it almost correct, you just need to do a little bit more

```
NSArray* items = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

if ([items count] > 4) {
   NSString *string = [items objectAtIndex:4];
}
```