# How to find words and full stop position from NSString in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I want to find any word or full stop from a nsstring.

```
NSString *str = @"Hi, my name is Tina. I want to ask something. I am trying a lot. But I am not able. To find full stop. Position Everytime. It come in str.";
```

In this I want to track the position of full stop not first full stop positions every full stop position in "Str".

I know how to find words but not able to get full stop position every time it come on my str.

Here is what am I doing

```
NSString *str = @"Hi, my name is Tina. I want to ask something. I am trying a lot. But I am not able. To find full stop. Position Everytime. It come in str.";

NSInteger count = 0;
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
{
    if([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"."])
    count++;

}
```

I don't want this as it give me str character length not by word. I want to check after how many words full stop is comming.

```
if ([str3 rangeOfString:@"."].location == xOut)  {  // dont want
```

or

```
if ([str3 rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound)  {  // dont want
```

Any Idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632672/nsstring-character-position) link it might help you

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Are you really looking for the positions of full stops or are you looking for sentences in the string?

Comment: I want to check full stop position after words. Menas in str after space first full stop is comming on position 5. And same for second full stop and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"Hi, my name is Tina. I want to ask something. I am trying a lot. But I am not able. To find full stop. Position Everytime. It come in str.";
[str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, str.length) options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [substring enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, substring.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%@", substring); // last word

        *stop = YES;
    }];
}];
```

This will give you the last word of each sentence.

Comment: how to put the value of substring to nsstring? means NSString *Str2 = substring;

Comment: __block NSString *lastWord = nil;

above the enumeration

then in the block, instead of the NSLog - lastWord = substring;

Answer (score 1):

Use this code -

```
NSString *str = @"Hi, my name is Tina. I want to ask something. I am trying a lot. But I am not able. To find full stop. Position Everytime. It come in str.";

NSInteger count = 0;
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

for(int i = 0; i< [arr count]; i++)
{
    NSString *sentence = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    sentence = [sentence stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *wordArray = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    count = [wordArray count];
    NSLog(@"No of words after full stop is comming = %i", count);

}
```

Comment: sentance is giving error, fast enumeration variable cant be modified in ARC by default: declare the variable_strong to allow this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *str = @"Hi, my name is Tina. I want to ask something. I am trying a lot. But I am not able. To find full stop. Position Everytime. It come in str.";

NSInteger count = 0;
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
{

       NSString *arrStr=[arr objectAtIndex:i];

       for(int j=0;j<arrStr.length;j++){

       NSString *Schar=[arrStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1)];

       if([Schar isEqualToString:@"."])

         count++;

      }



}
```

here,Count will show number of time . is in string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ following links :

```
NSUInteger numberOfOccurrences = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] count] - 1;
```

[Number of occurrences of a substring in an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166809/number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring)

[Number of Occurrences of a Character in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938095/nsstring-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character)

Hope this helps :)